# Can Google track the referring URL from their Google Maps URL Scheme on Android and iOS devices?

Tags: seo, google, analytics, mobile, google-maps

If you click on a Google Maps URL link (`comgooglemaps://`) on a website in Safari or Chrome on an Android or iOS device that opens up the native Google Maps App, can/does Google track the referring website that you clicked the link on?

For example: if you clicked on `comgooglemaps://?q=Pizza&center=37.759748,-122.427135` from `webmasters.stackexchange.com` in Chrome or Safari on iOS or Android, this takes you to the Google Maps native app. Can Google track the referring site (`webmasters.stackexchange.com`)? If yes, do they?

Comment: cross posting is not allowed,  have flagged with mods

Comment: This question was cross-posted to StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457427/is-it-possible-for-google-to-track-the-referrer-url-of-a-google-maps-url-on-a-mo

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: The questions are similar, but in this question I was asking if Google does track referrer URL in the described situation. In the StackOverflow question, I am asking if it is programmatically possible for Google to track a referrer URL in an app to app situation. I asked that in StackOverflow because Pro Webmasters is not a programmatic themed site.

Comment: So if the answer to that question is yes, that it is programatically possible, then Pierre-Marc David Caron here points out that they would likely do so.

Comment: I think Google definitely would if they could. The StackOverflow answer is saying that it is not programmatically possible for Google to receive the referrer URL since the communication is happening between two native apps which only send the Google Maps Scheme URL. Still not fully convinced that it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the Google's [Privacy policy](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/).

> **Log information**
>
> When you use our services or view content provided by Google, we may
> automatically collect and store certain information in server logs.
> This may include:
>
> details of how you used our service, such as your search queries.
>
> telephony log information like your phone number, calling-party
> number, forwarding numbers, time and date of calls, duration of calls,
> SMS routing information and types of calls.
>
> Internet protocol address.
>
> device event information such as crashes, system activity, hardware
> settings, browser type, browser language, **the date and time of your
> request and referral URL.**
>
> cookies that may uniquely identify your browser or your Google Account.

This policy is related to all the services and contents that Google offers, including Google Maps Apps and website.

To answer your question I would say yes they can track the referring Url and yes they do it.

Comment: Thank you Pierre-Marc. I know they track referral URL's under normal circumstances, but I am wanting to know for a fact if they can track it on iOS and Android devices from one native app to another.

Comment: They are able to track wich app or referal url have fired any their Apps (including Google Maps), On android or iOS they even made this feature availible to developpers through the [Anlytics SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/)

Comment: If you want see it by yourself you can use the [shark for root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&hl=fr) app(Android) exactly what requests(and where) the App is sending when you use it. I don't know if an app like this exist for iOS

Comment: @novicePrgrmr, why is this not marked as an answer, the answer answer here deserves the 50 bounty easily?

Comment: @DaveRook Because I saw a conflicting answer from a developer on StackOveflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457427/is-it-possible-for-google-to-track-the-referrer-url-of-a-google-maps-url-on-a-mo

Comment: A developer on StackOverflow says that it's not programmatically possible for Google to track app to app referrer URL's. Does his answer have merit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457427/is-it-possible-for-google-to-track-the-referrer-url-of-a-google-maps-url-on-a-mo

Comment: Both answers can be true. Joiningss's is a more optimistic point of view .The fact is when we deal with Google products and meta data(in this case refferal url) we can only guess what they are doing with it. From there I know 3 things 1. Its written in their Policy that they can do it. 2. They made tools to track it in their SDK, I assume they must be using them in their own apps. 3 They are selling ads and remarketing data as their main income, to be efficient they profile us at the best as they can.

Comment: The best way to be certain of its going on with the request made to the app would be to reverse engineer it.

Comment: I'd like to give you your bounty, but the question has been flagged. Hoping it gets unflagged soon.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr If you're good with this answer and want to award the bounty to it, you might have to select "Reward existing answer" since the answer appeared before the bounty was added - see "Can I award a bounty to an old answer?" [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).